# How to embedded Knowage to html

Tags: business-intelligence, spagobi

I a new user to **Knowage** BI. I want to know on how to embed **Knowage cockpit** into html.
So far I login as ***demo_admin*** and try to embed one of the cockpit to html using  but when I did the embed and go to the embedded html and it will ask to login again. After I login. it will show the error.

I do the research on embedded and someone said use the **SDK** but I don't know how :(. Can someone give me the reference to do?

Gladly if somebody can helps. Thanks.

Comment: following the same.

Comment: @MuhmmadAbubakarIkram here what i did
1. Download http://release.ow2.org/knowage/7.2.16/Applications/ and put in in the Knowage-Server-CE\webapps
2. Then u can try run http://localhost:8080/knowagesdk on web.